# How can I find the Windows domain logon name of a user from within Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

I need to figure out someone's login name for our domain, and I'd like to be able to do this from within Outlook 2010.  I used to be able to do this from Outlook 2007 by right-clicking the user's name in an email message that they'd sent me, and clicking "Outlook Properties..." in the context menu.  That would bring up this dialog, which contained what I need in the "alias" field:

[image: The dialog in Outlook 2007]

Now I've installed Outlook 2010.  I want to do the same thing, but I can't seem to find a corresponding field.  First, I don't see an explicit "Outlook Properties" menu option anymore, and what I think is the corresponding dialog looks completely different:

[image: The (I think) same dialog in Outlook 2010]

It seems weird that, although I'm looking at the properties of my own name in the same email message in 2007 and 2010 in these screenshots, my name is shown differently in each -- Chris versus Christopher.  That makes me think that Outlook isn't really looking in the same place to get this info in each case.  So, can I get that "alias" field from within Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on the usr name in the Address book, then click on the ICON furthest to the right with the drop down arrow. Select Outlook Propeties and there you go!

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's good to see that familiar dialog!  I see that I can doubleclick a mail recipient and get the little contact card and do this.  Oddly, when I doubleclick the mail *sender*, I get something different.